# While adding bootstrap 5 in my HTML page it shows this error in console. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. how to fix it?

Tags: html, bootstrapper

While adding bootstrap 5 in my HTML page it shows this error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. how to fix it?

i am adding these files.

for CSS

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

for JS

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It snot bootstrap 5 . Its Bootstrap `@4.6.0` you are adding. And i did not found any error in that

Comment: Remove the crossorigin tag. This error is due to cors

Comment: Ohh my mistake, I have added bootstrap 4 files. Bootstrap 4 is working fine. I have problem with BS5